# how to draw table using antd table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html-table, antd

I am using Antd table and I have my toys object as below

```
{
    "Truck": "Black",
    "Bike": "White",
    "Car": "Blue",
    "Bicycle": "Black"
}
```

Now I want a table using antd table as below. Here, the 1st column is text and the second column must be an input field, i.e., the color must be editable.

| Toys | Color |
| --- | --- |
| Truck | Black |
| Bike | White |
| Car | Blue |
| Bicycle | Black |

Can anyone help me to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the codesandbox, that I've created for you

https://codesandbox.io/s/antd-editable-0izgw

You need to pass `{editable: true}` only to make the column editable.

I've take the reference from `antd` official website. You can learn more [here](https://ant.design/components/table/#components-table-demo-edit-cell).